# How to remove the "(1)" suffix from the name suggestion in Windows 10 save/download dialogs

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, save-as

When I download a file with Chrome, I have configured Chrome to always ask where I want to store the file. So every time I download something, I'm prompted with a save dialog.

If the folder that is opened already contains a file with the exact same name as the one I am downloading, the suggested name in the save dialog has "(1)" added to the file name. So, if I download a file called "readme.txt" but a file with the same name already exists, the suggestion is to save it as "readme (1).txt"

I'm looking for a way to disable this "(1)" name suggestion. I prefer to overwrite files. Is there a setting for this?

Comment: It is only the suggestion since it knows you already have existing file. And my understanding the (1) is only if its an auto-download (auto saved, not prompted). If you set Chrome to Always Ask / Prompt - you can always set it exactly the same, and then you will be given a choice to overwrite. Unless you are hoping for it to auto-overwrite as default and don't prompt?

Comment: No, I'm hoping to skip some steps in the process of overwriting files manually. Right now I have to first remove all the extra characters, then save, then confirm that I want to overwrite. I mean, when I remove the characters I already know it's going to overwrite, that's why those characters are there in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never I suppose.

> Short Answer, Windows OS does not offer a user level setting to
> override this behavior, it appears this is an application level
> feature that must be accommodated. i.e. Chrome feature request

I think the long answer might be that this is a common feature among many applications and we hope there is control at the OS level, yet I have failed to find anything for Windows. Here are some threads on Mac/Linux specifically related to this:

Linux -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192520/disable-auto-number-duplicate-file-names-upon-save-dialog

OSX -> https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/460217/finder-disable-appending-of-1-when-saving-same-file-name-ie-no-versionin

Back on this being an application level feature request, I discovered a browser that broke this convention, however only short lived as the community requested it to be "patched" to force same file name versioning as a protection method to those unaware of a potential unwanted overwrite.

https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/issues/7764

The brave issue has been closed and archived so there is no way to provide input on this topic without opening another request to add this capability back in as an option we can toggle per our preference.

Update: On OSX at least, there appears to be a way for *some* applications to override this, maybe something similar exists for Windows - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/460217/finder-disable-appending-of-1-when-saving-same-file-name-ie-no-versionin

Comment: Hello, the question is for Windows, but I don't see any specific answer for Windows. Please keep in mind answers should cover the specific questions.

Comment: I agree, I've updated answer to reflect that the clear answer is that this is currently not supported as a setting in Windows but rather can be addressed at the application level, should the app developers consider to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem fixed with an xtensnion in Chrome - i thought - but my other computers dont seem to be able to manage.
It has worked for me for years !  download.xls downloads as download.xls no download(1).xls.  And it prompts to overwrite Y/N

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1191888)